# How to fix ActivePerl's PPM "database disk image is malformed" error?

Tags: sqlite, perl, activeperl

I've recently installed ActivePerl 18 (v5.18.2) 64bits on Windows 8.1, and ppm keeps producing the same error : DBD::SQLite::db selectrow_array failed: database disk image is malformed.

Here's an exerpt from my command prompt:

```
ppm install Win32-Console-ANSI
ppm install failed: DBD::SQLite::db selectrow_array failed: database disk image is malformed

ppm rep
ppm rep failed: DBD::SQLite::db selectrow_array failed: database disk image is malformed

ppm
ppm gui failed: DBD::SQLite::db selectrow_array failed: database disk image is malformed
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had similar problem.
I solved it, I cleanned AppData folder of ActivePerl. I found that under:

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\ActiveState\ActivePerl\

Remove all data from that folder.

Please try it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine by deleting "C:\Perl64\etc\ppm-perl-area.db" and C:\Perl64\site\etc\ppm-site-area.db".  Both were rebuilt when ppm was restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve mine by renaming the
 
**ppm-MSWin32-x64-multi-thread-5_20.db**

as
 
**ppm-MSWin32-x64-multi-thread-5_20.db_**

and then renaming
 
**ppm-MSWin32-x64-multi-thread-5_20.db.old**
in 
**ppm-MSWin32-x64-multi-thread-5_20.db**

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your DBD::SQLite package directly from CPAN.  Or, try telling PPM to upgrade everything.  If those don't want to work, you may need to reinstall ActivePerl.

HTH!
TheJester1977

Comment: Try downloading and installing the 32-bit version. I've found that sometimes 64-bit software packages don't play together as nicely as they should.